# SFML not working with c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to load SFML into my c++ project however, it is not working and I have no idea why.
When I build the project I am getting the following errors

```
Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class sf::RenderStates const sf::RenderStates::Default" (?Default@RenderStates@sf@@2V12@B)    C:\Users\liamkeenan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Game\Game\Game.obj    Game
Error   2   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class sf::Color const sf::Color::Green" (?Green@Color@sf@@2V12@B) C:\Users\liamkeenan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Game\Game\Game.obj    Game
Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup C:\Users\liamkeenan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Game\Game\MSVCRTD.lib(crtexew.obj)    Game
Error   4   error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals   C:\Users\liamkeenan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Game\Debug\Game.exe   1   1   Game
```

so can you please help me, I have no idea why I am getting these errors :/

Comment: Can I have a link to the duplicated question please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your errors are connected with linker, you should add all dependencies. In VS you can find it there "Project Properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies".

You should look at [this link](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.3/start-vc.php)  as well.

Comment: I have got under that option sfml-graphics.lib sfml-window.lib sfml-system.lib

Comment: Read the article I gave you.

Comment: If the link was helpful please mark my post as an answer :)